# iOS Firebase Messaging.messaging().unsubscribe(fromTopic: "some topic") doesn't work on background

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem in iOS app, when try to unsubcribe from Firebase topic, when app is on background (closed). I use Firebase pod.

Command
`Messaging.messaging().unsubscribe(fromTopic: "some topic")`
does nothing when app is on background.

I have method, which starts when message come from Firebase. It checks if user is active in database, and if not, tries to unsubcribe. It works well when app is active, but doesn't when it is on background (closed). I expect unsubcribing and next message doesn't come. But it comes.

Please, any idea why? Thanks.